# Using volume buttons while in sleep mode ( music player style )

Tags: android

I need to use volume buttons in my application while sleep mode is active( black screen, locked).
I am using onDispachKeyEvent to capture volume buttons and it works perfectly while in normal state.
In music player if you close the screen, you can still change volume. Any idea how is done ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a partial wake lock to get the host CPU to remain active while the device is in "sleep?" Or in your case I guess you just want to acquire the partial wake lock when the display goes off and release it when the display goes on.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently experimented quite a lot with that at my HTC Desire (and this got confirmed at several phones from another vendors).

The summary is the following: when screen is off – the volume buttons are listened by system only in case music is currently being played.

Even in this case you wouldn't  get volume button key press events in Activity when the screen is off - system just modifies the volume level of AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC when music is playing (and other corresponding audiostreams in different situations: alarm, phone call) - and doesn't do it when there's no music/alarm/call